# Why does my libgdx java desktop app have the wrong height?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

reference :https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SimpleApp

```
package com.badlogic.drop;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
      cfg.title = "Drop";
      cfg.width = 768;
      cfg.height = 1280;
      new LwjglApplication(new Drop(), cfg);
   }
}
```

In the main project

```
 Gdx.app.log("",Integer.toString(
              Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
```

outputs - 756

Comment: Is cdf.height related to Gdx.grpahics.getHeight()? Change cfg.height() to something really small and what does Gdx.graphics.getHeight() now say?

Comment: Creepy! What version of libgdx are you using? What OS are you running?  When in the application cycle are you logging the height? It is entirely possible this could be a defect.

Comment: ahh I got it, its my laptops height resolution - the top bar on mac. I thought setting it to a higher resolution will just scale the app to fit my screen, but it doesnt do that

Comment: any height I set above 756 gets reset to max which is 756

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark is as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The max height available is limited by your desktop/laptops resolution. Mine is 1280 x **768**. And mac has a finder bar on the top so maxHeight = 756, anything you try to set above it, just gets reset to 756.